# according to tutorial does not work - rubymine cucumber rspec

Tags: ruby, xpath, rspec

I created two files according to some tutorial(I could not find now)
first is steps:

```
Given(/^: i am on "([^"]*)"$/) do |path_to|
  visit path_to # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

When(/^: I type ".*?" in search field$/) do |string_search|
  TXT_SEARCH= ".//*[@id='masthead-search-term']" # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  BTN_SEARCH= ".//*[@id='search-btn']"
  find(:xpath,TXT_SEARCH).set string_search
  find(:xpath,BTN_SEARCH).click
end

Then(/^: i should see install cucumber$/) do |string_expectation|
  page.should have_content string_expectation # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

and second one is feature

```
Feature: as a consumer, i want to search th in yt

Scenario: search dth on yt
  Given : i am on "http://youtube.com"
  When : I type install cucumber in search field
  Then : i should see install cucumber
```

but when I try to run it does not work..I got an error

> You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:
>
> Given(/^: i am on "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1|
> (...)

Why? Everything is like on YT

Comment: The quickest guess would be that you have not required your step definitions in your testing environment.  Check cucumber-rails and/or rspec-rails gems for their installation procedure which takes care of the most common setup tasks.

Comment: `/^: i am on` there is a space between the `:` at the beginning of this and the `i` - it might not be relevant, but it also might - worth trying to remove the extra space, just in case it matters.

Comment: This is my code to environment"

Comment: Thanks. I installed ruby-rails gem now and deleted spaces, but still the same.link to screen: https://postimg.org/image/4pacpmakd/